# boost's regex won't compile

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, boost

I am using boost 1.45.0 on Ubuntu with Code::Blocks as my IDE, and I can't get basic_regex.hpp to compile. I'm pretty sure I set up boost correctly, because I can compile programs using boost::format without any errors. But I'm getting this annoying error, and I don't know how to get rid of it.

The code that is provoking the error:

```
boost::regex e("\"http:\\\\/\\\\/localhostr.com\\\\/files\\\\/.+?\"");
```

Compiler output (GCC):

```
obj/Debug/main.o
In function `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'

/home/neal/Documents/boost_1_45_0/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex.hpp|379|
undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'|

||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Did I miss a step when setting up boost, or should I downgrade to another version of boost?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like a linker error. boost::regex is not a header only library so you need to pass `-lboost_regex` with correct `-L/path/to/boost/lib` to linker.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was dead-on. :)

Answer (score 10):

Boost::Regex has some code that lives in a separate library (libboost_regex.so).  To link against it, add `-lboost_regex` to the GCC commandline you're using.

Depending on your install, that might be libboost_regex-mt.so.  In that case, you'll need to use `-lboost_regex-mt` on your command line.  (The MT stands for mutlithreaded.)

Comment: It wasn't a threading problem, but I'll remember your suggestion. =)

Answer (score 2):

That's a linking error rather than a compiler error. You need to explicitly link against Boost's regex library.

```
g++ program.cpp -lboost_regex -L/path/to/boost/lib
```